# Python xlrd считывание данных из нескольких листов с использованием sheet_by_index

Tags: python, excel, xls, xlrd

Как использовать `sheet_by_index` для открытия нескольких листов из xls файла? На выходе я хочу получить запись в списки из всех листов xls документа.
Пытался сделать таким образом:

```
import xlrd
   excel_data_file = xlrd.open_workbook('./test.xls')
        sheet_count = excel_data_file.nsheets
        for nsh in range (0,sheet_count):
        sheet = excel_data_file.sheet_by_index(nsh)
        ku_ind_lst = sheet.col_values(0)
        sys_name_lst = sheet.col_values(2)
```

Я немного модифицировал код, добавив считывание из двух листов другим способом, но тоже не получилось.

```
import xlrd

excel_data_file = xlrd.open_workbook('./test.xls')

sheet_count = excel_data_file.nsheets
print(sheet_count)

sheets = {}
for nsh in range (0,sheet_count):
        sheet = excel_data_file.get_sheet(nsh)
        sheets[sheet.name] = sheet
ku_ind_lst = sheets.col_values(0)
sys_name_lst = sheets.col_values(2)

for i in range(0, len(sys_name_lst)):
    if sys_name_lst[i] == 'xxx' or sys_name_lst[i] == 'yyy' or sys_name_lst[i] == 'zzz':
        b = sys_name_lst[i]
        c = ku_ind_lst[i]
        print(b)
        print(c)
```

И ко всему прочему решил проверить как будут считываться данные из xls файла с двумя листами с 5000 строк в каждом, появилась ошибка:

> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 699, in
>   get_sheet
>       raise XLRDError("Can't load sheets after releasing resources.") xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Can't load sheets after releasing resources.

То есть для моей задачи get_sheet не подходит? Можно ли использовать sheet_by_index для открытия нескольких листов из xls файла?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста суть вопроса. PS `.sheet_by_index()` можно использовать для открытия нескольких листов

Comment: Попробуйте оформить ваш в вопрос в соответствии с: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/). Т.е. привести в вопросе небольшой пример входных данных и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось предельно просто, использовал `.sheet_by_index()` в цикле:

```
sheet_count = excel_data_file.nsheets
print(sheet_count)
    for sheetno in range(sheet_count): 
      sheet = excel_data_file.sheet_by_index(sheetno)
      print ("Sheet name:", sheet.name)

    ku_ind_lst = sheet.col_values(0)
    sys_name_lst = sheet.col_values(2)
```